# Как определить, жив ли процесс? Python 2.6, unix

Tags: python, unix, процесс

Вопрос тут появляется в похожем виде не впервые. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: нужно проверять не только существование процесса, но и то, что он не является зомби.

```
try:
    os.kill(pid, 0)
    return True
except OSError:
    return False
```

Вариант выше знаю, он не прокатывает с последним условием. Ставить внешние программы/модули нельзя, все это происходит на разных машинах под линуксом и BSD, рутового доступа на которые нету. Есть какие-нибудь варианты, как решить проблему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно чисто средствами баша

```
ps aux | awk ' { print $2" "$8 } ' | grep -q "$pid Z"
```

где $pid это pid вашего процесса. В случае если процесс зомби, то результат этой команды будет равен нулю, т.е. полное совпадение.

Comment: работает, спасибо)

Comment: Хм, есть ненулевая вероятность того, что за время после смерти старого процесса стартует новый процесс, и он получит тот же id. (Новым процессом может быть, например, `sh`, `ps`, `awk` или `grep`.)

Comment: @VladD, насколько я помню, пока не достигнут предел PID, каждый новый процесс получает новый номер.

Comment: @mikillskegg: правда? не знал, тогда всё в порядке, вероятность можно считать нулём :)